# Firebase integration through Carthage gives error

Tags: ios, firebase, carthage

I have created an SDK(framework) in Objective C, which can be integrated by other third-party apps.

My SDK uses Firebase's MLVision, MLVisionFaceModel, and other features. While integrating with any third-party app, that other app must use the Firebase framework. The SDK integration works fine when a third party app uses CocoaPods for Firebase.

But the issue occurs when I try to use Carthage instead of CocoaPods for Firebase. With Carthage, I see library loading issue at run-time. I get an error message like below.

> dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/MyFramework.framework/MyFramework
>
> Referenced from:
>   /Users//Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/A3651DD6-F31D-4866-963F-12A57C575BEC/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/B4D47B47-16B0-42EC-8321-5BFD7D58DD45/FaceRectCarthage.app/FaceRectCarthage
>
> Reason: image not found

I have been trying to solve this issue for many days, but couldn't find any solution for it. Other people have also reported similar issues at Github.
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/1862

It is also mentioned that the Carthage distribution is still experimental.
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/master/Carthage.md

Now I am really not sure whether there is any solution for my problem available or not.

I am really bound to use Carthage only for one of my projects. CocoaPods is not an option for me for that particular project.

Can anyone please help me with this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try adding firebase with manual drag & drop ?

Answer (score 3):

Firebase is distributed as static frameworks and can not be linked into dynamic frameworks.

Firebase either needs to be linked directly into the app or `MyFramework` must be linked statically instead of dynamically.